# Nicer solution than appending empty string with conditional operator

Tags: c#, string-concatenation, conditional-operator

Almost daily I come across code of the following form:

```
string x = "foo" + (someTest ? "bar" : "");
```

Surely there must be a nicer way to succinctly append a string only if some value is true?

This:

```
string x = "foo";
if (someTest)
    x += "bar";
```

does not satisfy my appetite, because I often want to use the string directly (e.g. as a function argument), without storing it in a variable.

Comment: how come you're so sure there is a nicer way?

Comment: I'm not, it's just wishful thinking.

Comment: @Botz: without wasting performance and or memory, whilst behaviorally equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about an Extension Method?

```
string x = "foo".AppendIf(someTest, "bar");


public static string AppendIf(this string value, bool expression, string append)
{
    return expression
       ? value + append;
       : value;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but using expression before the string in the methods reads more natural then `"foo".AppendIf("bar", someTest);`
+1

Comment: agreed, like the ternary operator.

Answer (score 6):

Why not write your own extension method to do this?

```
public static string AppendIf(this string value, string toAppend, bool condition)
{
    return condition ? String.Format("{0}{1}", value, toAppend) : value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use extensions

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string AppendIf(this string s, bool condition, string append)
    {            
       return condition ? s + append : s;
    }
}

string x = "Foo";
x.AppendIf(someTest, "bar");

// or even

string y = "Foo".AppendIf(someTest, "bar");
```

Comment: I wish this "great mind" would leave, so I could say: "look at that esskar go!"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the string literals could also be variables:

if there is I have yet to find one.

I think the two examples you have are the best.

The only objection is that if you need to conditionally add many strings using the second solution with a stringbuilder instead of concatenation should be a better solution considering performance, readability and maintainability.

Deep nested ? : constructs can be very hard to follow, especially if there are multiple forks.

Comment: esskars solution is a nice way to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
string x = someTest ? "foobar" : "foo";
```

Comment: Aargh, the redundancy! I appreciate how it ditches the concatenation altogether, but the redundancy sticks out like a sore thumb.